# How do I get a glass jar out of refractory plaster?

Tags: glass, metalworking, plaster

So today I made a metal foundry with a 2/4 plaster 1/4 sand and 1/4 water mix and I put a glass jar in the middle of it to create room. But now the glass jar is stuck and I don't want to break it. Any ideas to get it out?

Comment: Break the glass into splinters, scrape them off the sides with an ice pick, then pour them out.

Comment: @HenryTaylor sounds like an answer?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I don't want to break the jar.

Comment: Figured that... which is why I offered it as a comment rather than an answer.  
@terrariabat, can you attach a picture or provide more description of your project.  From what you have provided, it is unclear whether the forged material envelops the jar (following its tapering shape) or just encircles the jar (leaving an open as big as the jar's largest demension through which it can be removed.   Chances are that if it only encircles the jar, you can remove it by heating up the forged material until it expands and releases the jar.  Next time use a mold release material such as Teflon spray.

Comment: Me and my neighbor ended up thermal shocking the jar so thanks for the help it is always appreciated!

Comment: If you had some before picture add that into the question and if you have after pictures I would add those into your self answer

Comment: Yeah my camera is broken or else I would have.

Comment: Still. __I encourage you__ to use your comment and flesh out an answer with it. Comments are fickle. Answers are best

Comment: y es I still have some of it stuck

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to carefully drill holes into the glass very near one another, and then gradually break pieces away with long nosed pliers, or if you have a dremel with a tip for grinding glass remove the glass that way once the holes are dilled. I'm assuming you can get to the glass, perhaps not.

A photo of the challenge would be a big help.

Am I assuming correctly the foundry can take a lot of heat? If so, then would a blowtorch on the glass melt it? (obviously the foundry will become exceptionally hot).